# Iteratively inputting a list of int into a dictionary of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this code:

```
test_dict = {'aaa' : [1, 2], 'bbb' : [4, 5], 'ccc' : [7, 8]}
lis = [11, 22, 44, 55, 77, 88]
```

I am trying to iteratively update `test_dict` to become:

```
test_dict = {'aaa' : [11, 22], 'bbb' : [44, 55], 'ccc' : [77, 88]}
```

The closest I've come to finding a solution is at:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-iterate-through-value-lists-dictionary/
(Method #1)
but I'm not sure where to break up that right side of the `res` variable to update `test_dict`.

Comment: Do the numeric values in `test_dict` have any meaning, or does it only matter how many there are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop and slice the list. The dictionary is updated *in-place*.

```
n = 0
for k, l in test_dict.items():
    test_dict[k] = lis[n:n+len(l)]
    n += len(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if you know that `lis` always has at least as many values as will need to be replaced, and the size of the lists in the dict are arbitrary, then you can use the following:

```
import itertools
test_dict = {'aaa' : [1, 2], 'bbb' : [4, 5], 'ccc' : [7, 8]}
lis = [11, 22, 44, 55, 77, 88]

iterator = iter(lis)

for vs in test_dict.values():
    vs[:] = itertools.islice(iterator, len(vs))

print(test_dict)
```

If `lis` is potentially smaller, then you can do something to the effect of:

```
iterator = iter(lis)

for vs in test_dict.values():
    for i, e in enumerate(vs):
        try:
            vs[i] = next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            # you could do something with e perhaps if you wanted
            pass
```

Which will only replace as many values are there are in `lis`. You could handle the `except` clause however you want, in this case, it just keeps what is there already (by doing nothing), but you could, for example, add a dummy value or whatever you want.

The above mutate the original dict. If you want to create a seperate, new dictionary, the approaches can be modified in the following way:

```
# we know lis has at least as many items as needed to replace
iterator = iter(lis)

new_dict = {k : list(itertools.islice(iterator, len(vs))) for k, vs in test_dict.items()}
```

Or, in case `lis` may have less items than will need to be replaced:

```
iterator = iter(lis)
new_dict = {}
for k, vs in test_dict.items():
    new_dict[k] = sublist = []
    for i, e in enumerate(vs):
        try:
            sublist.append(next(iterator))
        except StopIteration:
            sublist.append(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.12 introduces a function that lets you combine adjacent list entries. Combining this with the `zip` function and a dictionary comprehension gives you an elegant way to do what you seem to be describing.

```
from itertools import batched


test_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(test_dict, batched(lis, 2))}
```

Comment: **but** you assumed that all dictionary values are _always_ of the same size

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: `batched(lis, 2)` splits the the whole list in chunks of size 2, always

Comment: @Tux1 that you are assuming that all the sublists have the same exact length: 2. This *may* be a valid assumption, though. But why are you sorting `test_dict`? That seems like a bad assumption. in it should just be `zip(test_dict, batched_lis)`, and frankly, there is no need for the intermediate `batched_lis`, which kind of defeats the purpose of itertools. You should just do `{k: list(vs) for k, vs in zip(test_dict, batched(lis,2)}`

Comment: Dictionaries don't have orders, I'm assuming that original poster intends for the keys to be sorted alphabetically. That said, your corrected code does make the better decision of including the `batched` function in the dict comprehension directly, which I should have done.

Comment: that is incorrect, dictionaries maintain insertion order.

Comment: Oh... I'm both behind and ahead of the times apparently.